# SpeechRecognizer.SpeechRecognized Event is not working with Speech Recognizer (English-UK)

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, sapi

I created a simple grammar in C# and after that I used SpeechRecognizer.SpeechRecognized Event. but I don't know why it works with Microsoft Speech Recognizer (English-US), But it doesn't work with Microsoft Speech Recognizer (English-UK).

here is the code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognizer sr = new SpeechRecognizer();
        Choices Slist = new Choices();
        Slist.Add(new string[] { "Brazil", "Germany", "Argentina", "Netherlands" });
        Grammar gr = new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(Slist));
        sr.RequestRecognizerUpdate();
        sr.LoadGrammarAsync(gr);
        sr.SpeechRecognized += sr_SpeechRecognized;

    }

    void sr_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Result.Text.ToString()== "Brazil")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Fourth");
        }
        if (e.Result.Text.ToString() == "Germany")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("First");
        }
        if (e.Result.Text.ToString() == "Argentina")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Second");
        }
        if (e.Result.Text.ToString() == "Netherlands")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("third");
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which platform (System.Speech.Recognition or Microsoft.Speech.Recognition)?   Which OS (Vista, Win7, Win8)?

Comment: @Eric Brown As you can see in my code I'm using System.Speech.Recognition and I'm running this program in Windows Seven 64bit.

Comment: How are you switching between en-us and en-gb?  The code doesn't show a locale setting...  Also, are you sure the en-gb recognizer is installed?  My Win 8.1 machine, for example, doesn't have the en-gb recognizer installed by default.  Check Control Panel\Ease of Access\Speech Recognition\Advanced Speech Options to make sure the English - UK recognizer is installed.

Comment: @Eric Brown I just change the recognizer language in Advanced Speech Options in control panel and there is an English-UK recognizer installed.

Comment: ok; again, how are you specifying the en-uk recognizer?  As written, you're using the shared recognizer, which uses the SR default engine...

Comment: When I change the recognizer's language in control panel to en-UK it will result a change in the shared recognizer's language to en-UK. should I do something else?

Comment: No, that's fine.  WSR is working fine as well?

Comment: WSR is working fine, it is just the SpeechRecognizer.SpeechRecognized Event that is not working. I wonder if it lacks something in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Speech\Preferences\en-GB . Currently apart from (Default) string there is just HowDoITaskEnabled with the value of zero. If you have any other question tell me.

Comment: The only thing I'd do differently in your code is to move the RequestRecognizerUpdate() after the LoadGrammarAsync (and possibly move the RequestRecognizerUpdate into the LoadGrammarCompleted handler.  But if it works in en-us, it should work with en-gb, particularly if WSR is listening and working OK.

Comment: I did that, But it didn't help.

Comment: Are you getting other events (SpeechDetected, SpeechRecognitionRejected, SpeechHypothesized)?

Comment: SpeechDetected and SpeechRecognitionRejected are working but SpeechHypothesized is not working, like SpeechRecognized.

Comment: Try setting the [`Culture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.grammarbuilder.culture(v=vs.110).aspx) property on the `GrammarBuilder`.

Comment: It worked, Thank you very very much Eric, You saved me. If you want, you can write the answer so that I will be able to mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the [`Culture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.grammarbuilder.culture(v=vs.110).aspx) property on the `GrammarBuilder` object must match the Culture of the recognizer in order to get recognitions to work.